# How to convert .bmp alpa uncompressed into .bmp compressed with alpha?

Tags: gimp, bmp

How to convert a 32 bit(A8R8G8B8) **image(.bmp uncompressed /or .png) with alpha channel** into **.bmp RLE compressed with alpha channel** using **Gimp** or **ImageMagic** or any other open source tool?

Thanks,
Sridhar

Comment: RLE only works with 256 colors (from what I've read). I tried ImageMagick's `convert` and it lead to the same result, no matter what compression I use (*none* or *RLE*). Both files are exactly the same size. (BMP -> "compressed" BMP). Stick with PNG whenever possible, it yields smaller files.

Comment: @Steven: Tried both Gimp and ImageMagic. I could convert 32 bit .png into 32bit .bpm (without losing alpha channel). But I couldn't apply any compression if the image has alpha channel.

Comment: In Gimp there is an option for to change the image into indexed mode. After that mode change you could apply RLE but you will lose the alpha channel.